# Embed Geckofx 45 in Winforms VisualStudio

Tags: winforms, geckofx

I embedded Geckofx 33 in my winform application, but that version is too old for what i have to do, so i would like to figure out with the latest version of gecko embedding it in a winform.
Is this a way to do this with the latest version of gecko??
And if yes, does the latest version support the mp3/mp4?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At this point no, there is not a way to use gecko 45. There have been substantial changes since 33 that require some work before we can move forward. However there are plans to start work on 45 this month. If you sign in to https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/, you can follow the project and should get a notification when 45 is added.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much. I will follow the project of course

Comment: Update: it turned out to be an even bigger task than expected. hindlemail reports that he's making good progress and hopes to get remaining tests passing around the the beta release date of 45.

Comment: Well, we will wait for it :D